# Placing the equal sign (=) when merging the data frame and final writing the file writeLines or write.table

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe, merge

I have a data frame given below. there 29 variables and its values. I want to write it with `write.table` or `writeLine`, but I want to place the equal sign `(=)` between them.

```
              Variable    2
1         HYDRUS_Version    4
2              WaterFlow    0
3        SoluteTransport    0
4              Unsatchem    0
5              Unsatchem    0
6                    HP1    0
7          HeatTransport    0
8  EquilibriumAdsorption    0
9         MobileImmobile    0
10       RootWaterUptake    0
11            RootGrowth    0
12       MaterialNumbers    0
13      SubregionNumbers    0
14             SpaceUnit   cm
15              TimeUnit days
16            PrintTimes  160
17       NumberOfSolutes    0
18      InitialCondition    1
19         NumberOfNodes  101
20          ProfileDepth  120
21      ObservationNodes  160
22           GridVisible  160
23            SnapToGrid  160
24          ProfileWidth  160
25            LeftMargin  160
26              GridOrgX  160
27              GridOrgY  160
28                GridDX  160
29                GridDY  160
```

I need output like this in text file.

```
HYDRUS_Version=4
WaterFlow=0
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=0
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=0
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=0
SubregionNumbers=0
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=120
ObservationNodes=160
GridVisible=160
SnapToGrid=160
ProfileWidth=160
LeftMargin=160
GridOrgX=160
GridOrgY=160
GridDX=160
GridDY=160
```

further I will will split this file into parts and write some characters between these two parts and will get the final `.txt` file.

Comment: Did something with `write.table(your_data, "file.txt", sep = "=")` not work? Or maybe the problem was with the `?write.table` command?

Comment: it not worked. I tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
writeLines(paste(df[[1]], df[[2]], sep="="), file="output.txt")
```

Comment: same issue as I mentioned in comment to Matt Tyers.

Comment: Fix your data, and the solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps, with dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=letters[1:4], y=1:4)
df
#   x y
# 1 a 1
# 2 b 2
# 3 c 3
# 4 d 4

write.table(paste(df[,1],df[,2],sep="="), row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F)
# a=1
# b=2
# c=3
# d=4

# and this gets you what you need...
write.table(paste(df[,1],df[,2],sep="="), row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F, file="asdf.txt")
```

Comment: your code loks cool. but in my data its results are HYDRUS_Version=c(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
WaterFlow=c(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
SoluteTransport=c(6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5) and continued for all the variables in same manners.

Comment: i checked my data. class(show)   it shows [1] "data.frame". so I applied your code from write.table but the results are annoying.

Comment: what happens when you run the `paste()` bit by itself, without wrapping it with `write.table()`?